# Browser error when loading PDFs with Adober Reader (Ubuntu 10.04, FF 4.01)

Tags: firefox, browser, pdf-reader

Browser cannot load PDFs with Adobe Reader installed and effective as default viewer.

> Could not launch Adobe Reader 9.4.2.
>   Please make sure it exists in PATH
>   variable in the environment. If the
>   problem persists, please reinstall the
>   application.

FF 4.01
Ubuntu 10.04

How do I make this error go away?

Answer (score 1):

What I just did was going into the Firefox Tools/Plugins menu and disable the Adobe Plugin. When I open a PDF URL, it will automatically ask if I want to save or open it. I choose "open" and it works now.

This is the first time I was having this problem with this version on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall Adobe Reader. If 9.4.2 is your version, you're running an older one, 10.0.1 is out now. I think if you install the updated one it should fix your problem.

Comment: Is 10.0.1 available for Linux?

I couldn't find it and neither could these people: http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/questions/789161 .

I'm getting skeptical of the update solution.  Never works for *any* of the problems I have.  :|

Comment: Hmmm, looks like the Linux version hasn't been updated yet. You could try an alternative PDF reader, I've used Foxit before. http://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf/desklinux/

Comment: This issue remains unresolved.  :(